# Creating an AWS disk that I can access from separate servers

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I would like to use a load balancer to rotate traffic between two separate servers. These servers will need access to a single data store (to save files, documents, images, etc.). Is it possible to do this on AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot share an EBS volume between two active instances.
2. You can certainly create an architecture that shares a datastore using any number of solutions, including fileshares, CM platforms, AWS S3, etc.

Comment: NFS as well....

Comment: if a few big files then i vote for S3 ... BTDT

Answer (score 0):

AWS announced [Elastic File System](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) so this is now possible.

Comment: They announced that they will be doing a "preview" on the West Coat (Oregon). They don't even have a date for that...